# xml code with php?

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml file code (from a page flip) and want to know if I can use a php while loop to generate the code in the xml file instead of manually having to type out from pages/ab74 to pages/ab98?

```
<page src="pages/ab62.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab63.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab64.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab65.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab66.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab67.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab68.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab69.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab70.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab71.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab72.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab73.jpg"/>
<page src="pages/ab74.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  I'm a bit confused by your question... where are your page src urls coming from? Do you want to generate/save xml files or serve xml to the browser?

Comment: Hi, I am doing a brochure page flip for a client and to display all pages of the brochure the pageflip im using requires each page to be listed as above in an xml file. But I wanted to use a php loop in the xml file to save me having to list out pages 1-98. Is this possible and if so, could you tell me how as this is all very new to me and I really appreciate your help. Do I also need to add an xml doctype etc?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. If you want to do it on a constant basis, you'll have to set the content-type to xml and use a URL Rewrite to allow your file.xml to point to an actual .php file.

```
<?php for ($i = 74; $i <= 98; $i++): ?>
<page src="pages/ab<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg"/>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing a brochure page flip for a client and to display all pages of the brochure the pageflip im using requires each page to be listed as above in an xml file. But I wanted to use a php loop in the xml file to save me having to list out pages 1-98. Is this possible and if so, could you tell me how as this is all very new to me and I really appreciate your help. Do I also need to add an xml doctype etc?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally, yes it's possible. If this is all your XML is (which it shouldn't be because it's lacking a root node), then you just need to use a `for()` loop. Otherwise, have a look at the PHP [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) library.

Comment: Hi, I am doing a brochure page flip for a client and to display all pages of the brochure the pageflip im using requires each page to be listed as above in an xml file. But I wanted to use a php loop in the xml file to save me having to list out pages 1-98. Is this possible and if so, could you tell me how as this is all very new to me and I really appreciate your help. Do I also need to add an xml doctype etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
$page = "<page src=\"pages/ab%d.jpg\"/>";
for($i = 62 ; $i <= 98; $i++)
{
    printf($page,$i);
}
```

Full Example Creating Page Flip Config File

```
$xmlFile = "xml/Pages.xml";
$xml = '<content width="600" height="800" bgcolor="cccccc" loadercolor="ffffff" panelcolor="3a6dac" buttoncolor="3a6dac" textcolor="d0e5f7">';
$page = "<page src=\"pages/ab%d.jpg\"/>\n";
for($i = 62 ; $i <= 98; $i++)
{
    $xml .= sprintf($page,$i);
}
$xml .= '</content>' ;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml->saveXML($xmlFile);
```

Comment: many thanks for all your replies - it really helps when starting out

Answer (score 1):

did you mean that?:

```
<?php
for($i=75;$i<=98;$i++)
{
    echo '<page src="pages/ab' . $i . '.jpg"/>' . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is just some output operation:

```
$image = "<page src=\"pages/ab%d.jpg\"/>\n";
foreach (range(62, 74) as $number) {
    printf($image, $number);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing a brochure page flip for a client and to display all pages of the brochure the pageflip im using requires each page to be listed as above in an xml file. But I wanted to use a php loop in the xml file to save me having to list out pages 1-98. Is this possible and if so, could you tell me how as this is all very new to me and I really appreciate your help. Do I also need to add an xml doctype etc?

Comment: @RobHarris: Please stop spamming. And if it's your job, do your job. Do you want training?

Comment: sorry, not spamming, didnt know if I had to reply to each individual - sorry new to this !